# kendo chart display 0 value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I display correctly a funnel dataviz kendo-Ui chart, it works great except when my `dataItem` is 0
I want it to display in my label so I made a custom label:

```
 seriesDefaults: {
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent",
                    color:"white",
                    format: "N0",
                    template: "#= dataItem.type # - #= dataItem.value#"
                },
                dynamicSlope: false,
                dynamicHeight: false
            },
```

I get my data from a Json call which return 0.

How should I do to make my funnel display the label even if the `dataItem.value = 0`?

Comment: You can try missingValues:"zero"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended by doing quick and dirty fix, i replaced 0 by 0.000001 and rounding at display it's dirty but it works.